# Difference between spring modules and spring starter modules

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What is the difference between spring modules (e.g. spring-boot, spring-web and etc) and spring starter modules (e.g. spring-boot-starter, spring-web-starter and etc)?

And which one should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Spring Boot Starters** were built to address the issue of dependency management. Dependency management can become very complex over time and you can spend a long time managing them in your project versus focusing on issues that really matter, like your business logic and bug fixes. Spring boot starters are a set of dependency descriptors that you include in your service.

Take the MongoDB starter for instance:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/pom.xml

It has all the dependencies you need to connect to a MongoDB instance, all you need to do is add the starter to your service pom.xml and some configuration.

**Spring modules**, on the other hand, are part of the core spring runtime framework. They provide the fundamental  parts of the framework such as IoC and Dependency Injection.